# "Закон сохранения энергии". Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Фраза такая: "В фильме это называют "закон сохранения энергии". Я написал "закон..." в кавычках. Но, с другой стороны, данный закон, точнее, его формулировка в кавычки не берется. Так вот, нужны ли они тут?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В такой формулировке, возможно, кавычки и нужны, ибо здесь предполагается или допускается использование как своего рода имени собственного. Но тогда и писать "Закон" стоит с заглавной.

В нормальной же, не акцентированной фразе было бы, имхо, "В фильме это называют законом сохранения энергии" - тут уж ни о каких кавычках речи не идет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, уместна ссылка на Розенталя: http://www.e-reading.biz/chapter.php/48854/73/Rozental%27_-_Spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyku._Punktuaciya.html
(см. примечание в конце).

"Подлинные выражения" - т.е. в точности так, как сказано в источнике. Аналогично прямой и косвенной речи, скорее всего (Он сказал: "..." и Он сказал, что...)